# Does tables under schema uses multiple tablespaces other than default tablespace

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, oracle-11g

I have schema `A` in a database and have assigned the default tablespace as `myspace`.

There are 20 tables that reside under this single schema and all the tables are using different tablespaces.

My question is:

Why are all tables using different tablespaces instead of the default tablespace?

Answer (score 1):

A default tablespace is just that, a default.  If you specify a different tablespace when you create a table, the table will be created in the tablespace you specified.  Though it would generally not make sense to do so, you could put each table in a different tablespace so that the user owned 20 tables in 20 different tablespaces none of which were the default tablespace.

Alternately, a user's default tablespace can be changed so it is possible that the 20 tables were created without a specified tablespace but when the user's default tablespace was different.  Then the user's default tablespace was changed after all the tables were created.